# Slice a Dataframe Index per year - Python - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with daily stock data for the last 10 years, here is a slice of the dataframe :

```
            ITUB4   ITUB3
DATE        
2007-04-26  13.46   11.12
2007-04-27  13.49   11.00
2007-04-30  13.19   10.92
2007-05-02  13.57   11.09
2007-05-03  13.90   11.25
... ... ...
2017-12-21  42.72   37.39
2017-12-22  42.52   36.99
2017-12-26  42.69   37.44
2017-12-27  42.46   37.46
2017-12-28  42.57   37.68
2641 rows × 2 columns
```

Is there an easy way to slice this dataframe per year ? I know it is possible to do it by using :

```
df['20061230':'20071231']
```

I was wondering if there was something like :

```
df.index.year['2017']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `df['2017']` or `df.loc['2017']`. pandas is smart enough to understand it is the year part of a DateTimeIndex (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing)).

I prefer `loc` as it is more obvious this is an index operation - not a column one.

```
df.loc['2017']
Out: 
            ITUB4  ITUB3
DATE                    
2017-12-21  42.72  37.39
2017-12-22  42.52  36.99
2017-12-26  42.69  37.44
2017-12-27  42.46  37.46
2017-12-28  42.57  37.68
```

Answer (score 4):

Use boolean index i.e

```
df[df.index.year==2017]

        ITUB4  ITUB3
DATE                    
2017-12-21  42.72  37.39
2017-12-22  42.52  36.99
2017-12-26  42.69  37.44
2017-12-27  42.46  37.46
2017-12-28  42.57  37.68
```